# Numpy: Apply np.vectorize to arrays with dtype=object

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mapping, vectorization

I have a numpy array with some circular data. I want to replace each of this float data with a vector of its cosinus and sinus values.
To map this, I converted the array as `dtype=object` and applied a vectorized function on it.

But this raises an error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`
Probably this is a numpy bug?

Here is some example code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np

# Define a random array 'a' with dtype 'object'.
a = np.pi * np.random.rand(3, 2).astype(object)
tmp = a[0, 0]

# No problem to set any list to 'a'.
a[0, 0] = [1, 1.5]
print(a)

# Reset 'a'.
a[0, 0] = tmp
print(a)

# Map a function on 'a' with np.vectorize.
vectorize = np.vectorize(lambda x: [np.cos(x), np.sin(x)])
vectorize(a) # <-- Value error will be raised.
print(a)
```

Comment: `np.frompyfunc` is better for object dtype.  It's faster and returns objects

Comment: @hpaulj: You shouldn't write this as a comment but as an answer. So I can mark it as accepted. It is working as wanted, thank you! :)